# Unable to debug/test my react-native app on expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am new to react-native using expo. On opening expo app and scanning QR code from http://localhost:19002/ , I get tunnel connected but in my device there is always error stating Something went wrong or in http://localhost:19002/ I get error log as We noticed your tunnel is having issues. This may be due to intermittent problems with our tunnel provider. If you have trouble connecting to your app, try to Restart the project, or switch Host to LAN.

Here is the code which I am trying to test in my mobile device.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.title}> Cart </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to
          get a shareable url.
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  header: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    height: "10px",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#232323",
    color: "white"
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: "0 auto",
    textSize: "6px"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your debugging device and computer should be connected to same WiFi

Comment: initially when I installed expo app on my device, it worked but after few times of usage it started displaying as go back to home or reload. with Module AppRegistry is not registered callable module